# hook_preprocess_views_view not loading view when records are empty

Tags: views, theming, hooks

I am trying to add some css and js files using the hook_preprocess_views_view_unformatted Hook in template.php

Here is my code :

```
function mytheme_preprocess_views_view_unformatted(&$vars) {
$view = $vars['view'];
if ($view->name == "my_view_name"){

        drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('theme', 'mytheme') .'/css/sample.css', array());
        drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'mytheme') .'/js/sample.js');

}}
```

My problem is that when the view is empty or when does not have any records the view is not loaded and thus I am unable to get the $view->name and neither are the css,js files being applied for the page.

It is working fine when the view displays a few records. So is there any other hook or method to fetch the view name or get it loaded when the records are empty ?

Comment: I think you misunderstood how it works. If result set is empty there is no need to display view, except you added behavior for empty result.

Comment: Ohh ok thanks for that info. So which hook can I use to include my css, js files for my specific view ? I need to check the view machine name and attach my files.

Comment: I tried your hook implementation and it works fine. Just add some content for your view and look at result.

Comment: Yes the code works fine when view has records. but my view uses a exposed filter. Upon the filter selection of view returns empty then this hook does not work and neither are my css, js files getting applied.

Comment: So, in this way you should understand that empty view can be processed only if records exists or empty behavior was added.

Comment: Please consider answering your own question by filling out an answer below. It's not useful to put it in the question.

Answer (score 1):

---

I found out the solution to add files to specific 'View Pages'. Need to use hook_preprocess_page in template.php and check the view_name. Here is the code that worked for me.

```
function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$variables){
if($variables['page']['#views_contextual_links_info']['views_ui']['view_name'] == 'my_view_name'){
    drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('theme', 'mytheme') .'/css/sample.css', array());
    drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'mytheme') .'/js/sample.js');}
```